# Getting polygons of all countries and ISO-3166-2 subdivisons

Tags: openstreetmap, polygon, reverse-geocoding, county, region

In order to do reverse geocoding lookups to find a country (as ISO-3166-1) and the subdivision (as ISO-3166-2) for given coordinates I am looking for a way to get all polygons of all countries and their subdivisions.

Reverse geocoding lookups with Google Maps or other services either do not always return the country and subdivision (Google Maps), or sometimes they are incorrect (geonames.org). As I understand it all countries and subdivisons are available in the openstreetmap data, but I do not know how to only retrieve the polygons - no map data, no points of interest or cities are necessary, only the outlines of all subdivisions with the given country and subdivision codes. Then I can check myself if a given point is within any given polygon, or near it.

Does anyone know how to retrieve this data from the openstreetmap data, or is there any other source for this data?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Full list of ISO ALPHA-2 and ISO ALPHA-3 country codes](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/full-list-of-iso-alpha-2-and-iso-alpha-3-country-codes)

Comment: https://www.data.gouv.fr/en/search/?q=D%C3%A9partement and Wikipedia has the information from ISO 3166-2. Here's a general topic (in French): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codes_g%C3%A9ographiques_de_la_France

Comment: ISO 3166-2 isn't the area, but the name (or more specifically, how the administrative subdivisions are managed). Are you looking for the areas or the names?

Comment: The area. I would like the area coordinates in order to draw them on a map or a sheet.

Comment: http://www.gadm.org/country will probably help. I'd go with shapefile as a starting point unless you know you need something else.

Comment: I think your question might be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I also find http://geopandas.org/ which seems to be helpfull to read and use shape files with python

Comment: The Open Data Stack Exchange Q&As on [ISO 3166-1 and ISO 3166-2 data plus borders (e.g. as kml)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5186/iso-3166-1-and-iso-3166-2-data-plus-borders-e-g-as-kml) may be what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This site may have what you are looking for:

- http://www.gadm.org/ and http://www.gadm.org/country

Comment: I've checked out gadm and was able to test it - the provided data is really good, and most importantly, the ISO 3166-2 codes are contained (usually in the hasc_1 column, sometimes in the hasc_2 column). Some manual processing is still necessary depending on what kind of details one wants, but the source material seems great so far.

Comment: @iquito: FYI those values in the HASC_* columns are *not* ISO 3166, they're a [totally different thing](http://www.statoids.com/ihasc.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can find a script inspired by MvG's answer and a few examples here : 
https://github.com/laem/regions-topojson

Sadly, not all geonames administrative relations are tagged with iso-3166-2...

Answer (score 1):

Other sources include [Second Administrative Level Boundaries (SALB)](http://www.unsalb.org/) and [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/Data).

Answer (score 1):

Since you requested how to extract this data from openstreetmap: theoretically you can use the [XAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/XAPI#Tag_Predicates) to match [boundary](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Boundaries) descriptions. E.g. using a query like this: *(warning, will take quite a while, so I'm not formatting this as a link!)*

`www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?way[bbox=2,49,7.5,54][boundary=administrative][admin_level=2]`

The result will be a list of polygons, in this case denoting the boundaries of the Benelux countries. You'd probably have to repeat this for other bounding boxes, perhaps with overlap. And for other levels. Lot of work. You'd want a script for that.

Or download [Planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm), and simply use suitable [OSM libraries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks) or XML tools to locally extract the relevant data.

All of this will come without uniform ISO-3166-2 identifiers, as far as I can tell, simply because that standard isn't available for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a complete set of country boundaries, with first-level administrative subdivisions for most countries from GADM, here: https://gadm.org/download_world.html

Comment: I would love to know why this answer was downvoted, considering the ultimate question is "Does anyone know how to retrieve this data from the openstreetmap data, or is there any other source for this data?" I mean, what answer could be better than providing a link directly to the exact data they want?

Comment: probably the reason could be that the first (top) answer corresponds GADM data