# Get a list of all countries and their states?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries

I'm searching for a data set that contains the country information (Name, ISO 2 char, ISO 3 char, ISO number, ...) and other data. Also I'm looking for all states for each country including their abbreviation.

I'm willing to pay for that data if it is verified, actual and gets updated from time to time. I've already tried searching but couldn't find anything reliable.

Please note that I don't need geographical information directly but just a table of the data above.

Comment: Your keywords include "county". Did you mean "country"? Since country data and first order political divisons are easily obtained, you really ought to define "reliable".

Comment: Oh, yes, but I can't add a new tag. Clicked on the suggested "county", misread it.

Comment: "States for each country" - not all countries have such subdivisions, especially small countries like Andorra and Leichtenstein.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good data set from Natural Earth that contains countries and their admin units. As far as I remember abbreviations and ISO codes are also included. The data is free and more or less up to date. Have a look:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/

Maybe this post is helpful too:

[Full list of ISO ALPHA-2 and ISO ALPHA-3 country codes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/full-list-of-iso-alpha-2-and-iso-alpha-3-country-codes)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Global Administrative boundaries](http://www.gadm.org/), it provides different levels of aggregation. However, the last update was in January 2012. A well done list including other free GIS datasets is available on [RT Wilson's blog](http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/).

The [global insight](https://www.ihs.com/products/oil-gas-cartographic-data.html) dataset is also very comprehensive and regularly updated, but it is not free. It includes political boundaries (with ratified boundaries) as well as county/provinces.

Answer (score -1):

I am using this and works great !! 
https://www.universal-tutorial.com/rest-apis/free-rest-api-for-country-state-city