# Repository where I can find old / obsolete ISO3166 codes of countries including previously existing ones

Tags: data, geocoding

Where can I find old ISO3166 codes for countries including the ones that do not exist anymore, changed their name, etc.? I need this for all years 1961 through 2021. All I could find online was up to date ISO3166 codes.

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about it is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have found smilar questions with good answers such as: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/seeking-full-list-of-iso-alpha-2-and-iso-alpha-3-country-codes?newreg=56fe0cef9339489baa67a428da587b2c       on here so I decided to ask here.

Comment: That question was asked in 2010 when many SE sites were in their infancy and their scope quite fluid. Open Data SE did not exist until a few years later.

Comment: @PolyGeo , Oh I see thank you for the information